# File IO unit test in C

Tags: c, unit-testing, logging, io

I need to write unit tests for a simple logger implemented in C (unit tests are in c++).

I'm searching for a way to mock an unsuccessful 'write' to the log file ,in order to see that the logger to responds appropriately and returns an error.
I tried renaming the log-file before writing on to it:

```
static bool fileWriteMiss() {
  const char* testFile = "missLogFile.log";
  const char* movedFile = "missedLogFile.log";
  ASSERT_TRUE(
      spLoggerCreate(testFile, SP_LOGGER_DEBUG_INFO_WARNING_ERROR_LEVEL) ==
      SP_LOGGER_SUCCESS);
  rename(testFile, movedFile);
  ASSERT_TRUE(spLoggerPrintError("MSGA", "sp_logger_unit_test.c", __func__,
                                 __LINE__) == SP_LOGGER_WRITE_FAIL);

  spLoggerDestroy();

  return true;
}
```

and I tried deleting the log-file before writing on to it:

```
static bool fileWriteMiss() {
  const char* testFile = "missLogFile.log";
  ASSERT_TRUE(
      spLoggerCreate(testFile, SP_LOGGER_DEBUG_INFO_WARNING_ERROR_LEVEL) ==
      SP_LOGGER_SUCCESS);
  remove(testFile);
  ASSERT_TRUE(spLoggerPrintError("MSGA", "sp_logger_unit_test.c", __func__,
                                 __LINE__) == SP_LOGGER_WRITE_FAIL);

  spLoggerDestroy();

  return true;
}
```

**ASSERT_TRUE** function is implemented in an assertion library that is assumed to work properly.

**spLoggerCreate** is the initialization function of the logger structure (I'm being careful not to call it construction and object since the implementation is not oop, but pure C code).

Comment: C does not support _methods_. And `ASSERT_TRUE` does not look like one.

Comment: Unit tests are written in c++.

Comment: If this is C++ code use the correct tag! Nevertheless, it is not a _method_.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to return errors from log messages? I have never seen a program which checks if each log write succeeded or not. People usually prefer "graceful failure" with minimum performance impact.

Comment: Well, to be honest, it started as an assignment I got in software class. And it turned out that it's not really needed  but I address it now as an educational challenge. Of course there is a massive redundancy here, but yet - I'm going to get it to work!

Comment: Can you use [`setrlimit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setrlimit.html) or similar functions to limit the size of file that you can create, so you end up with a SIGXFSZ signal as you try to create a larger file?

Answer (score 1):

A working hack is to write to file that you cannot write to (please note that you can write to non-existent file in an existing directory - it would be created). There are few ways, some os-dependent:

- write to a file in non-existing directory. While it is complicated in a generic case, you can use some tricks like using chars unlikely to meet in a filename, like '\x01'.

  `const char* testFile = "non-existent\x01dir/missLogFile.log";`
- write to a file you have no rights to write to. In UNIX you can issue

  `chmod a-w file.log`

  command on an existing file to revoke write permission.
- write to a system read-only pseudo-file.

  `const char* testFile = "/proc/uptime"; // linux`

  `const char* testFile = "CLOCK$"; // windows / dos`

I believe unit-tests should never access OS, and your test becomes non-unit this way, but this is a terminology question and a holy war subject.

Update:

Your comment actually makes it a poorly asked but pretty interesting question. I think you can edit it and I will try to answer. As things go hacky here, I'll focus on Linux only, answering the question

**"How to make file open-for-write succeed, but subsequent write fail?"**

Probably the most common error real application face is "No space left on device". This is easy to reproduce in hermetic way: let us create a fat16 filesystem in local file, precisely:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=test_disk bs=1048576 count=1
$ mkdosfs test_disk
$ mkdir /tmp/mnt
$ sudo mount -o loop,rw,umask=000 test_disk /tmp/mnt/
```

Now fill the filesystem. Alternatively we could use smaller size.

```
$ perl -e 'print "a"x(1024*1002)' > /tmp/mnt/a.txt
$ echo test > /tmp/mnt/test || echo "can't write test file"
```

And finally hit the error:

```
$ echo `perl -e 'print "a"x4096'` > /tmp/mnt/test || echo "test succeeded"
bash: echo: write error: No space left on device
test succeeded
```

To be precise the error is encountered writing byte 1009:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/mnt/
total 1004
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1026048 Mar 27 17:56 a.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    1009 Mar 27 17:57 test
```

A nice side effect of FAT filesystem is that now you are free to open more files there and write will fail from byte 0, as you asked.

Comment: I want to be able to open the file, and fail to write to it. Your suggestions will not allow me to even open the file (+ the first has been already implemented :) )